# Which internet blackout technique works best?

Tags: html, css

I am thinking of various ways to blackout my site for a blackout protest. Which technique would work best?

Method 1 (easiest): Replace existing style sheet with a new one that has this code in it:

```
* { display: none; }
```

The benefit here is that search engines can still crawl the site, and people that are familiar with the protest and likely to understand its ramifications can still view the content by viewing source. The downside is that people might think something is wrong as there is no content at all displayed (I am fine with that).

Method 2: Add a `background-color: #000;` to `body` and `color: #000` to all text elements except for any text element that may be describing why the site looks different. The benefit to this is that more people will understand what is happening.  The disadvantage is that it does not really portray the message of the protest.  Also, I think it may be bad practice to give text the same color as the background as it is a proven spam technique.

Method 3: Display a test pattern.

Comment: Just route all requests to a "stop SOPA" placeholder page?  Take a look at [Sopa Blackout](http://sopablackout.org/).

Comment: [Website outages and blackouts the right way](https://plus.google.com/115984868678744352358/posts/Gas8vjZ5fmB)

Comment: @JoeTuskan: unfortunately, that might be severely misunderstood as a simple server crash.  I think the idea is to educate people, so you should at least serve *something*.

Comment: If everyone can still access all your HTML and data, then you're not really supporting the cause. The point of the blackout is to make it **unavailable** and make people realize what the internet will be like if PIPA passes. This will then motivate them more to protest it. If you're just making it all invisible on the page, you're only achieving this with people who are too lazy to just look at the source.

Comment: @aminuson: What if my content is actually information about SOPA/PIPA and contacting representatives?  The site will still show blank (which would seem like it is unavailable), but whoever is willing to dig, will find content that is relevant to the protest.  It also does not affect the crawl issue Greg Hewgill's link mentions.  And I would still like people with screen readers to be able to access the pertinent information which I guess Andre Caron's link also addresses.  I still have one hour to make up my mind.

Comment: @thequerist: Then you'll probably not want to bother blacking out or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many sites just block out their logos or have a dismissible dialog. I think you can still support a blackout protest without a 503. The point is to make people aware of the problem. You can put up a full-page fixed black div with a message and a link to relevant information. Even a banner about it would be helpful in getting the word out.

Here's what I'm using at http://thinkingstiff.com (link potentially NSFW due to language):

```html
<a id="sopa" href="http://sopablackout.org/learnmore/">**** SOPA</a>
<style>
#sopa {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font: normal 150px/500px Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial;
    height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: -11px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    word-spacing: 50px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I went with something similar, though not as NSFW as yours. :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a new page that returns an HTTP 503 response code and a response body with regular content. It won't hurt your SEO ratings and it won't affect the rest of your site.